# plsql Trigger error ORA-00604

Tags: plsql, triggers

Following Trigger created in a user anu

```
create or replace trigger audit_creation1
before create
on schema    
begin
    insert into audit_creation
    values(audit_creation_s1.nextval,
           ora_dict_obj_owner,
           ora_dict_obj_name,
           sysdate);
end;

create table cc(cid number);

ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-30511: invalid DDL operation in system triggers
```

This worked before many times. It was working successfully.

But now it's throwing error.

Comment: Are you sure that's the only trigger? I don't see any DDL in it, unless there is a trigger on the audit_creation table. Maybe you could catch it in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Throw a command

```
purge recyclebin;
```

as your trigger owner (`anu` in your case).